# Numberphile's "Why 82000 is an extraordinary number" applied to negative bases?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binary, number-systems

In a [numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNS1fabDkeA/) it is shown why 82000 is an extraordinary number. It can be written using only zeros and ones in base 2, base 3, base 4 and base 5. It is unknown if there are larger numbers for which this is true, and if it can apply to base 6 and higher.

$82000_{10}=10100000001010000_2=11011111001_3=110001100_4=10111000_5$

My question is: is there a similar "special" number that can be written using only zeros and ones in decreasingly negative bases (base -2, base -3, base -4, etc)?

Using python I found that from -100000000 to 100000000 the most negative number that can be written in base -3 and base -4 is $-196335$, the most positive one is $4353$.

Comment: In other words, a number is "writable" with only $0$'s and $1$'s in base $b$ if it can be written as the sum $\sum_{i \in P} b^i$, where $P \subseteq \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}$ is the set of positions where there are $1$'s (starting from the right and counting from the $0$th position).  And you want to know what numbers can be so written in many different negative bases $b$?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for the largest (or most negative) number that can be written in increasingly more negative bases using only zeros and ones.

Comment: For positive bases, a quick search shows that the largest such number for $N<10^{12}$ is $N=82000_{10}$. It should be interesting to know if a coincidence of four bases would appear again

Comment: Hm, it seems using negative bases is more difficult. Using odd primes we have,$$x + x^5 + x^6 + x^7 + x^8 + x^9 + x^{10} + 
  x^{13} = y^2 + y^3 + y^5 + y^6 + y^8 + y^9 = -1550100$$ where $x=-3$ and $y=-5$.

Comment: Unfortunately $−1550100_{10}$ is $132132211310_{-4}$.

Comment: I'm running a program to find these numbers. Numbers that can be written in both base -3 and base -4 are already rare. The largest I found was $-196335$.

Comment: From -100000000 to 100000000 the most negative number that can be written in base -3 and base -4 is $-196335$, the most positive one is $4353$.

Comment: There's a discussion of this property of 82,000 (and the unsuccessful  search for larger numbers with the same property) at http://oeis.org/A146025 – also related are http://oeis.org/A258981 and http://oeis.org/A258107 But oeis doesn't know about -196335.